# Default pixel value of line-height?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about finding the default `line-height` value in a pixel amount?

Does it just default to the `font-size`?

In an empty `html` file with `<!doctype html>` the default computed value of `line-height` is *normal*.

[image: Screenshot of inspector in computed value]

Comment: According to mdn, it is [roughly 1.2 em](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height).

Comment: What @chipChocolate.py said, however [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) doesn't specify it explicitly: `[...] We recommend a used value for 'normal' between 1.0 to 1.2`.